# python requests not working with access token with bearer token

Tags: python, python-requests, access-token, rest

access token is dynamically generated with each time and passed to the requests, its throwing invalid token error .
The access token is dynamically passed and bearer, i am not sure the bearer is correct format to send the token in header, Please correct the error

```html
import requests
    Access_URL = 'https://host1/uaa/oauth/token'
    client_id='ReadUser1'
    client_secret='clientsecret1'
    grant_type='client_credentials'
    BASE_URL='https://host2/hisrian-rest-api/v1/tags?nameMask=*&maxNumber=500'
   response = requests.post(Access_URL,
                        auth=(client_id, client_secret),
                         data= 
  {'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret,'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
   json_response=response.json()
   tokenvalue= (json_response['access_token'])

   headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
               'Authorization': Bearer {}".format(tokenvalue)}
   auth_response = requests.get(BASE_URL,  headers=headers)

   print(auth_response.json())
```

Comment: I think the issue is BASE_URL.

And header pass like ( headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenvalue,'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

Access_URL = 'https://host1/uaa/oauth/token'

client_id = 'ReadUser1'
client_secret = 'clientsecret1'
grant_type = 'client_credentials'
BASE_URL = 'https://host2/hisrian-rest-api/v1/tags? 
nameMask=*&maxNumber=100'
response = requests.post(Access_URL,
                     auth=(client_id, client_secret),
                     data={'grant_type': grant_type, 'client_id': 
client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret, 'content-type': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
json_response = response.json()
tokenvalue = (json_response['access_token'])
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
       tokenvalue, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
auth_response = requests.get(BASE_URL,  headers=headers)
print(auth_response.json())
```

Comment: if access token is passed manually it works but above methods throws error. below is the error
{'error': 'invalid_token', 'error_description': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImprdSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYnJ0Yy1t}